# Reuse Oauth2 credentials to access YouTube api

Tags: java, android-studio, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I will go step by step
First user login to google and I show what request permission I need for YouTube and I get credentials and I call YouTube api instantly after getting credentials and this part is working fine my issue is I want to again call the YouTube api inside my app and It need Oauth2 which is already done my user while login so who do I get the already login user credentials in another activity and then call the YouTube api whenever I want without again and again asking for user to select account

Comment: Okk I will put my code too and help me out

Comment: You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and supply a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

As long as your application has an access token, which hasn't expired, you can call the youtube API without having to ask the user to login again. If you received also a refresh token, you can use it to get another access token when yours expires, again without any interaction from the user.

Access and refresh tokens are issued for your app, so you can use them from any activity.

Comment: Can you provide me some tutorial over it

Comment: I don't have any tutorials, I'm afraid, you would have to try to google for them (I think googling for "android youtube api tutorial" should give some results). Still, if you managed to get access token once, you should keep it in an object which will be accessible by both your activities. Then in the other activity you can just use the token to perform a call to the youtube API.

Comment: @jayeshjain  SO does not supply tutorials you need to do your own research https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**